# NestJS connect to websocket inside route

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket, nestjs

I looked at implementing WebSocket connection in NestJs but most places are importing module in AppModule or if don't they just don't work.

My case is I have route making POST request to some random endpoint on the internet and the response from this endpoint is websocket URL. I need to connect to that URL and wait for data. After i get this data I send It as my route response.

what I did is

```
let socket: Socket | undefined;
    if (websocketUrl) {
      socket = io(websocketUrl, { secure: true, reconnection: true, rejectUnauthorized: false });

      await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        socket?.on("connect", () => resolve(console.log("connected")));
        socket?.on("connect_error", (error: Error) => reject(error));
      });
    }

    if (socket) {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("in promise");
        if (socket?.connected) {
          socket.on("onMessage", (data: any) => {
            console.log(data);

            try {
              if (data.type === "failed") {
                reject(new Error("Rejected"));
              } else {
                const stringData = data.payload.redirect;
                console.log(stringData);
                resolve(stringData);
              }
            } catch (err) {
              reject(err);
            }
          });

          socket.on("error", (error: Error) => {
            socket.off("onMessage");
            reject(new Error(`Websocket error ${error.message}`));
          });

          socket.on("disconnect", () => {
            socket.off("onMessage");
            reject(new Error("Websocket closed"));
          });
        } else {
          reject(new Error("Websocket is not connected"));
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw new Error("Websocket connection failed.");
    }
```

unfortunately when I'm running my function server throws error

```
XHR Polling Error
```